# How do we sign an iPhone application using someone else's Enterprise program?

Tags: iphone, code-signing, enterprise

We wrote an iPhone application that we want to sell to companies.  The company is enrolled in the iOS Enterprise program.

How can we sign our application with their certificate?  I know we can be added as a Team Member to their account, but is there any other way.

The company is a little uneasy about us generating a Certificate Request where one of their Admin members would actually create the profile.  They are worried that we could sign other applications with this profile.

Is there any other way without us giving up the source to our application?  In short, we wrote the application but want the company to sign the application using their Enterprise program and certificate.  We also want to be conscious of their security concerns.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can generate the IPA binary with your own certificate (or unsigned) and ship it to the company who can then resign it with the codesign utility:

```
codesign -f -s (name of certificate) /path/to/application
```

Comment: Is this in their documentation somewhere and have you tried this approach?

Comment: I just read this http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/272130-re-signing-iphone-app.html after your comment.  Is this the approach?

Comment: Yes, that's essentially the approach.  The -f switch is in the manpage for codesign.

Comment: Much appreciated!  Great answer and I would award more if I could.  :)