# iOS enterprise license + outside developer. Need iOS dev login credentials?

Tags: ios, xcode

Suppose one party has an enterprise license and wants to use an app developed by another party, an outside developer. Can the developer compile the app using the enterprise distribution certificate and provisioning profile *without* the other party's enterprise program login credentials? Or will these be required when the certificate is added to the developer's keychain?
Thanks

Comment: I suggest asking this on an Apple forum or at apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6686487/3009) regarding resigning an app with your own certificate.