# How to create self-signed ipa for iOS apps?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4, self-signed

I want to create a self-signed IPA using XCode for an iOS app I have written. I want to ship the ipa to customer who can sign the app and create an ipa using his code signature. 
Can someone help me with this ?

P.S: I know how to codesign an application using certificate I have in my keychain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You will have to send the source code to your customer, and he will need to build the app.</strike>

If you don't want him to have access to some/all of the source code, you could compile it as a dynamic library, and create a skeleton Xcode project that he can compile.

Edit: I found this question, with an answer. It looks like you can sign it with your own account, then send it to a customer to be re-signed by them using the `codesign` binary:

[How do we sign an iPhone application using someone else's Enterprise program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686487/how-do-we-sign-an-iphone-application-using-someone-elses-enterprise-program)

Comment: This is not true. One of our vendors sent us their ipa file and I have codesigned it with our certificate.

Comment: When I try archive one of my apps with code signing turned off (in project settings and target settings), I get: CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 5.0'

Comment: Not true. I don't know how to do it, but it's possible.

Comment: Looks like you guys are right, I found what looks like the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686487/how-do-we-sign-an-iphone-application-using-someone-elses-enterprise-program

Answer (score 1):

Just sign it with your own Developer certificate.  The customer can re-sign the app with any of their own certificates, using the codesign utility.