# How to sell a not self-developed app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store

I'm currently working on an app for a customer of mine and it will be soon released.
My customer wants to sell the app by himself and so i'm wondering, whats the best way to accomplish this.

He could register for the developer programm and i could send him the source code. He only needs to compile and submit it - but if its rejected, he gets the information and not me (who needed it most XD).
What to do here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would have him create his own Developer account, and add your Developer profile onto his team. You can be on multiple teams with your account, one for your independent development, and one as a developer for another company. That way, he can sell the app himself, but you can still submit it and handle any updates / possible rejection.

Comment: oh, that sounds good - so he have to register as a company... am i right?

Comment: @jacksbox Yes he would, although I have not tried this under an account registered as an Independent.

Comment: ok, i ll do it save and tell him to register as a company. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

so if he gets an information I'am definitely sure that he will inform since you are the person who developed it. Just make sure that you inform him that since he is going to register you will not be responsible if it gets rejected.

Answer (score 0):

He will need to handle that himself. He needs to register for a developer account and publish the app himself. From there, if it does get rejected for any reason, he can handle it by relaying any information necessary to whomever.

Due to rights, he should own the account used to publish the app. Avoid frustration down the road, do it right.

If he absolutely does not want to maintain the account himself, you can register an account FOR HIM, but the account should be owned by the customer. His name needs to be on it when it is registered. From there, you can handle inquiries related to the account / app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like [iresign](http://code.google.com/p/iresign/) to resign the app on his end. No need to send him the source code just so that he can release it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is ship him the binary you create and have him sign it before submitting it.  See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686487/how-do-we-sign-an-iphone-application-using-someone-elses-enterprise-program/6686589#6686589).